# Identify different users on a single android device using Fingerprint

Tags: java, android, android-fingerprint-api

I am facing an issue where I have to be able to identify users on a single android device using fingerprint alone. The users that will scan their fingers on said device will not have registered fingerprints on this device.

I read that android does not expose fingerprint images because of security reasons, but I was wondering is there a way to get a form of a fingerprint image that is specific only to the app it is running in?

**Scenario:**
There will be one android mobile phone at reception in a building. All of the employees has to register their fingerprints in the same app, but using their own smartphones.

**What I Need To Do:**
I need to be able to capture a form of a fingerprint image on all the different smartphones and then save them to a central DB. I also need to be able to validate the fingerprint once again when they scan it on the central smartphone at reception and be able to match it up to that specific employee.

I would like to know if anyone knows if this will be possible given the strict security rules of android's Fingerprint Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering is there a way to get a form of a fingerprint image that is specific only to the app it is running in?

Not using standard Android hardware. Some form of external fingerprint reader might offer an SDK that supports your use case.

Comment: do you know any 3rd part SDK , plz share

Comment: @HariShankarS: I have never looked for one, sorry.